# How to access inkscape installed on host machine in to docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-container

I have a requirement where I am converting svg in to png for which I am using inkscape .
On local machine I have installed inkscape by using following command

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

And than I run my project through wsl and it works fine .

Now I am deploying my code.
I have created the image and deployed it in docker container.
I also installed the inkscape on the host machine .

Now I am running the code so it is throwing error that says :

```
File or directory not found :inkscape
```

How can I access the inkscape in my container ?

Comment: A container can't invoke programs that live on the host machine; they need to be installed in the Dockerfile.  What does your current image look like?

Comment: @DavidMaze which means I need to pass the instructions inside docker file to install the required program and than create a image?

Comment: That's correct.  The image should be self-contained and include everything you need to run the application, including any support binaries.

Comment: @DavidMaze my base image in docker file is FROM python:3.10 .. so I need to write instruction below Run apt-get update && apt-get install inkscape

Comment: Will it work ? Or I need to change anything else

Comment: That seems likely to work.  What happens if you build the corresponding image?

Comment: I am just confused that update command will everytime download the list of packages amd upgrade already installed packages. @DavidMaze

Comment: `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` are different commands.  Another Stack Exchange site like [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] might be better places to ask about how to work with the Debian package management tooling.